How to Implement External Payment Processing in Flutter without Using In-App Purchases?
I'm developing a Flutter application where I need to handle payments without using the in-app purchase mechanisms provided by Google Play Store and Apple App Store. This is necessary because the payments are for services that are online courses
i have used razorpay to receive the payment. It works fine on google play store.
In app store i dont want to give commission . Please suggest some workaround to this
